How do I make one to many relationship for a parent class and a child enum in flask sqlalchemy?
Here is my parent class:
class Parent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    children = db.relationship(...(please help here)...)

Here is my child enum:
class Child(Enum):
    CHILD1 = 'child1'
    CHILD2 = 'child2'
    CHILD3 = 'child3'

Here are the things I know for sure:

There will always be fixed Child options (only 3 child in this example). They cannot be modified in run-time. That's why I chose enum.
I do not want to make an entire table in database for Child. But it is ok to make a parent_child table that maps which child's parent is who.
Finally, each parent can have multiple children.

I tried adding this for my parent_child table:
parent_child = db.Table('parent_child',
                         db.Column('parent_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parent.id'), nullable=False),
                         db.Column('child', db.Enum(Child), nullable=False)
                         )


"each parent can have multiple children" -> so a parent could have 3 * child1, 7 * child2, 0 * child3 for example?

sorry, I should've clarified further. For a parent, child1 can be only one, child2 can be only one etc. But for now, multiple child1 will also work.
